# What is the most efficient way to calculate installed base?

Tags: c#, sql, excel, optimization, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement to calculate the installed base for units with different placements/shipments in different countries with different "environments" over many years given a set of certain "retirement rates" assigned to each unit. The placements, curve definitions, and curve assignments are stored in different database tables (with DDL and sample data below, also on [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0995/2/0)). The formula for calculating installed base is as follows:

[image]
where 1990 is the first year for which we have placement data.

## The problem:

Doing these calculations with datasets of 3 to 16 million rows of unit/country/environment/year placement combinations takes much more time than the target load/calculation time of 30 seconds to 1 minute.

### Sql Server approach

When `PIVOT`ed so that each year becomes its own column, I get anywhere from 100,000 t0 400,000 returned rows of raw data (placements + rates), which takes about 8-15 seconds. However, if I were to calculate this manually via SQL statement as included below, it takes *at least* 10 minutes.

We've also tried an SQL trigger solution that updated the installed base each time a placement or rate was modified, but that made database updates unreasonably slow on batch updates, and was also unreliable. I suppose this could merit more investigation if this were really the best option.

### Excel-VSTO approach (so far, the fastest approach):

This data ultimately ends up in a C# VSTO powered Excel workbook where the data was calculated via a series of `VLOOKUPs`, but when loading 150,000 placements across 6 years by about 20 `VLOOKUPs` per cell (about 20 million `VLOOKUPs`), Excel crashes. When the `VLOOKUPs` are done in smaller batches and the formulas are converted into values, it doesn't crash but it still takes much longer than one minute to calculate.

## The question:

Is there some mathematical or programmatic construct that would help me to calculate this data via C# or SQL more efficiently than I've been doing? Brute force iteration is also too slow, so that's not an option either.

```
DECLARE @Placements TABLE 
(
    UnitId int not null,
    Environment varchar(50) not null,
    Country varchar(100) not null,
    YearColumn smallint not null,
    Placement decimal(18,2) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (UnitId, Environment, Country, YearColumn)
)


DECLARE @CurveAssignments TABLE 
(
    UnitId int not null,
    Environment varchar(50) not null,
    Country varchar(100) not null,
    YearColumn smallint not null,
    RateId int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (UnitId, Environment, Country, YearColumn)
)

DECLARE @CurveDefinitions TABLE
(
    RateId int not null,
    YearOffset int not null,
    Rate decimal(18,2) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (RateId, YearOffset)
)

INSERT INTO
    @Placements
    (
        UnitId,
        Country,
        YearColumn,
        Environment,
        Placement
    )
VALUES
    (
        1,
        'United States',
        1991,
        'Windows',
        100
    ),
    (
        1,
        'United States',
        1990,
        'Windows',
        100
    )

INSERT INTO
    @CurveAssignments
    (
        UnitId,
        Country,
        YearColumn,
        Environment,
        RateId
    )
VALUES
    (
        1,
        'United States',
        1991,
        'Windows',
        1
    )

INSERT INTO
    @CurveDefinitions
    (
        RateId,
        YearOffset,
        Rate
    )
VALUES
    (
        1,
        0,
        1
    ),
    (
        1,
        1,
        0.5
    )

SELECT
    P.UnitId,
    P.Country,
    P.YearColumn,
    P.Placement *
    (
        SELECT
            Rate
        FROM
            @CurveDefinitions CD
            INNER JOIN @CurveAssignments CA ON
                CD.RateId = CA.RateId
        WHERE
            CA.UnitId = P.UnitId
            AND CA.Environment = P.Environment
            AND CA.Country = P.Country
            AND CA.YearColumn = P.YearColumn - 0
            AND CD.YearOffset = 0
    )
    +
    (
        SELECT
            Placement
        FROM
            @Placements PP
        WHERE
            PP.UnitId = P.UnitId
            AND PP.Environment = P.Environment
            AND PP.Country = P.Country
            AND PP.YearColumn = P.YearColumn - 1
    )
    *
    (
        SELECT
            Rate
        FROM
            @CurveDefinitions CD
            INNER JOIN @CurveAssignments CA ON
                CD.RateId = CA.RateId
        WHERE
            CA.UnitId = P.UnitId
            AND CA.Environment = P.Environment
            AND CA.Country = P.Country
            AND CA.YearColumn = P.YearColumn
            AND CD.YearOffset = 1
    ) [Installed Base - 1993]
FROM
    @Placements P
WHERE
    P.UnitId = 1
    AND P.Country = 'United States'
    AND P.YearColumn = 1991
    AND P.Environment = 'Windows'
```

Comment: This sounds like the kind of summary data that I usually keep in a separate table.  The table can be updated daily, or at some other suitable interval, with a scheduled job.

Comment: Does this data need to be "real time" or is it acceptable to have some delay in calculation?

Comment: *When PIVOTed so that each year becomes its own column, I get anywhere from 100,000 t0 400,000 returned rows of raw data (placements + rates), which takes about 8-15 seconds.* What do you mean by this? Does this mean you used the PIVOT clause?

Comment: @HABO: thanks for the comment. I did that for our last iteration. I disabled the triggering of the table update because users ultimately want a real time solution, and the update was taking too long. It might eventually come to that again.

Comment: @dana: Thanks for your comment, similar to HABO's. It made me realize that this might prompt an honest conversation with users about the pros/cons of "real-time" data vs "real-time" load, since if the two are equivalent (10 minutes to load/seconds to update in one scenario and the converse in the other), both are effectively "real-time".

Comment: @ConradFrix: That's right, I did mean the TSQL `PIVOT` clause.

Comment: This would seem to need a divide and conquer solution. Can you run multiple threads against the database, by any chance? Then you could break up the problem and add the reults. Should be what you need. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm

Comment: @uvesten: Will look into it. Do you think you could post an answer that includes a successful implementation of this approach? Regardless, I'll test over the weekend and update with my progress.

Comment: @PeterMajeed well if you've got a solution that < 20 seconds why can't you just do that. Also try experimenting with temp tables instead of table variables. I've experienced problems with them in the past for large sets of data in earlier versions

Comment: @ConradFrix: Yeah, sorry if I was unclear about what happened in that load time. It takes < 20 s for the placements/rates to return, but it's the calculation of the IB from placements/rates that takes a long time. Re: temp tables, thanks for the advice. I find table variables more convenient for SO examples, and I believe I use temp tables for most/all large production calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this might turn out to be a case where asking the question leads to the right answer. It turns out the answer mostly lies in the query I'd given above, which was entirely inefficient. I've been able to get load times in the vicinity that I'm looking for by just optimizing the query as below.

```
SELECT
    P.UnitId,
    P.Country,
    P.YearColumn,
    P.Environment,
    P.Placement,
    sum(IBP.Placement * FRR.Rate) InstalledBase
FROM
    @Placements P
    INNER JOIN @Placements IBP ON
        P.UnitId = IBP.UnitId
        AND P.Country = IBP.Country
        AND P.Environment = IBP.Environment
        AND P.YearColumn >= IBP.YearColumn
    INNER JOIN @CurveAssignments RR ON
        IBP.UnitId = RR.UnitId
        AND IBP.Country = RR.Country
        AND IBP.Environment = RR.Environment
        AND IBP.YearColumn = RR.YearColumn
    INNER JOIN @CurveDefinitions FRR ON
        Rr.RateId = FRR.RateId
        AND P.YearColumn - IBP.YearColumn = FRR.YearOffset
GROUP BY
    P.UnitId,
    P.YearColumn,
    P.Country,
    P.Environment,
    P.Placement
```

Answer (score 1):

In response the following statement:

> We've also tried an SQL trigger solution that updated the installed
>   base each time a placement or rate was modified, but that made
>   database updates unreasonably slow on batch updates, and was also
>   unreliable. I suppose this could merit more investigation if this were
>   really the best option.

Have you heard of [SQL Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx)?  One of the things it does really well is allow you to queue data for asynchronous processing.  If the trigger itself is too slow, you could use the trigger to queue records for asynchroneous processing.

Comment: No, I haven't! Asynchronous processing might be the way to go. I'll look into it and let you know how it works out.